# OpenLdap. Switch to mdb-backend (Memory-Mapped Database)

Tags: ldap, debian, openldap

I`ve installed OpenLdap v.2.4.39 for Debian 7. But during setup I have only 2 option for backend: BDB and HDB.

[image]

But I want to use MDB (http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/backends.html). AFAIK it is stable. How to choose it as backend?

Thank you!

PS. i can see mentions about hdb in below files:

```
/etc/ldap/slapd.d# grep -nr hdb *
cn=config/cn=module{0}.ldif:7:olcModuleLoad: {0}back_hdb
cn=config/olcBackend={0}hdb.ldif:3:dn: olcBackend={0}hdb
cn=config/olcBackend={0}hdb.ldif:5:olcBackend: {0}hdb
cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif:3:dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb
cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif:6:olcDatabase: {1}hdb
```

But I am not sure if I can edit them.

Comment: why do you provide the output of `grep -nr hdb *`? i don't understand how this makes sense in the context of your question.

Comment: I`ve posted current db backend which used my installation. I suppose that I should change these values to migrate to mdb.

Comment: while it doesn't help with answering your question, would you mind replacing that image with a textual description of it's content? the text is really just unreadably tiny on a huge blue image (and it's easy to put into words, that debconf just gives you the choice between `A` and `B`). removing the image might allow visually impaired people helpe you as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian the `MDB` backend has been enabled since `slapd-2.4.39` which is available since Debian *jessie* (the code-name for the current **testing** distro).

assuming, that you are using Debian/stable (aka *wheezy*), the answer is simple:

> your version of slapd has been built without *mdb* support, so you cannot use it.

if you are using slapd>2.4.39 (which seems to be the case according to your comment), you must configure the backend manually (as there is no `debconf` template yet that supports MDB).

checkout `man slapd-mdb`

Comment: I`ve installed slapd from jessie and 2.4.39 my current version of slapd.

    # dpkg -l | grep slapd
ii  slapd                              2.4.39-1                   amd64        OpenLDAP server (slapd)

Comment: Installation of slapd-2.4.39 doesn't have slapd.conf but "man slapd-mdb" advise to add "database mdb" option to slapd.conf for enabling mdb.

Comment: It's true. As I can see now, in slapd v2.4.42 MDB can be seen on ncurses setup page.

Answer (score 4):

The module is there, the deconf template is not.

```
$ ls /usr/lib/ldap/back_mdb*
/usr/lib/ldap/back_mdb-2.4.so.2  /usr/lib/ldap/back_mdb-2.4.so.2.8.3      /usr/lib/ldap/back_mdb.la  /usr/lib/ldap/back_mdb.so
```

To enable, we need to load the module first.

```
$ cat someEpicLdif.ldif
# we need to load the mdb module first
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap
olcModuleLoad: back_mdb

# now we configure our mdb backend
dn: olcDatabase=mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: mdb
olcSuffix: dc=ldap_is_bananas,dc=org
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=ldap_is_bananas,dc=org
olcRootPW: changeme
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcMonitoring: TRUE
olcDbEnvFlags: writemap
olcDBNoSync: TRUE
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword by dn="cn=admin,dc=ldap_is_bananas,dc=org" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by * read
olcAccess: to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: to * by dn="cn=admin,dc=ldap_is_bananas,dc=org" write by * read
```

Please don't copy and paste man slapd-mdb and man slapd-config for the configuration options and supply your own.

Then add the new backend using ldapadd, if you're using SASL binds...

```
$ sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ldap_is_bananas.ldif
```